# RAD Studio Pros and Cons

Tags: android, ios, c++builder, codenameone

I have worked a little with Codename One and have built a simple app (I also tried out other frameworks like Xamarin, JQuery, Sencha, NSBApp etc.), but I have no experience with RAD Studio XE5. It claims to be a WORA Tool. I tried to find out the pros and cons of this framework but couldn't find good and neutral resources. Has anybody deep experience with RAD STUDIO creating mobile apps? It would be nice to give me some Infos about it? I realized that the developer and customer community of RAD Studio is not vast. What is the reason for it? Do anybody knows the differences and similarities between RAD Studio and Codename One (which is also a WORA Tool)?
Just for info: I was looking for different frameworks to build apps for IOS and Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codename One and RAD Studio XE5 are really nothing alike.

Codename One - Java

RAD Studio XE5 - C++/Pascal

Codename One - cloud build - hence doesn't require Mac etc.

RAD Studio XE5 - compiler toolchain

Codename One - mobile first

RAD Studio XE5 - desktop tool migrated to mobile

Codename One - open source + premium SaaS subscription

RAD Studio XE5 - proprietary license

It's really a matter of what you are comfortable with and personal preferences. I used to love Delphi in the 90's but haven't looked back at it since Java came along.

Comment: Shai, there are really big similarities between the two platforms. Of course there are two different programming languages, but: 1. Both of them are WORA Tools. 2. You can build apps with both of them for IOS, Android ... 3. The end product is native app. I mean points like needing a Mac, licenses or the language are not big issues. What is important to me, is the performance of the product, the components it provides and the native look. Is there a difference between them?

Comment: By the way RAD Studio claims that their apps are faster because they use native language. Therefore they run directly on the CPU but Java is slower because it is using a virtual machine. What do you think about it? I would appreciate to hear your oppinion.

Comment: We translate Java to C for iOS and Java is the "native" of Android so those claims are probably targeted at PhoneGap or interpreters.

Comment: RADStudio compiles to CPU-native code, not platform-native code.  So on iOS and Android, it compiles to ARMv7 assembly code that runs directly on the CPU, it does not compile to ObjectiveC or Java that can run on any platform-supported hardware. However, it does provide bridge classes to access platform-native ObjectiveC/Java APIs from C++/Delphi source code.

Comment: Correct, I don't think this negates what I said or implied right? IMO that's a problematic approach e.g. with Apple adding 64 bit support etc. which is exactly why we chose to use the intermediate stage to be 100% compatible with Apple into the future.